# Clone a sub-directory in git

Tags: git

I have the my remote and local git repository on the same unix box. 
I was able to clone the entire repository to my local folder. 
My requirement is to also clone a sub-directory.

For instance , this is what i want to achieve.

1. Remote repository (directory structure)

   - src
   - folder1/server
   - folder2
2. In my local repository i want the directory like

   - src
   - folder1/server
   - folder2
   - server (this is the same server under folder1)

When I tried using sparse checkout, I get this error :
"error: sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory"

Comment: Have you considered using a symlink?

Comment: Yes i have considered using a symbolic link. But its not what i need.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve that a symlink won't allow you to do?

Comment: I am migrating code from cvs to git, so when I checkout code from cvs I get the above directory structure,. I am trying to achieve the same when I checkout/clone the git repository.